# Objective-C: Dynamic binding changes a variable's declared class type?

Tags: objective-c, casting, dynamic-binding

I'm new to `objective-c`. I was learning about using `id` just now and have written the following code:

```c
NSString *str = @"x";
id obj = str;
NSArray *arr = obj;
NSLog(@"%@, %@\n", str.className, arr.className);
```

Executed in Xcode, output is `__NSCFConstantString, __NSCFConstantString` without any warnings. May someone tell me why this happens, considering `arr` is initially declared as an `NSArray`?

I also tried to directly assign `arr` to `str` as follows:

```c
NSString *str = @"x";
NSArray *arr = str;
NSLog(@"%@, %@\n", str.className, arr.className);
```

Although a warning has been raised in xcode, it can be successfully executed and the output is the same `__NSCFConstantString, __NSCFConstantString`. Why?

I've spent quite some time searching on the Internet, but haven't found a good answer. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Can you show declaration of s variable?

Comment: @Greg: That's probably a copy/paste error and should be `str`.

Comment: @Greg: Sorry about the typo. I just corrected it

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, `str` and `arr` are pointers to the *same object*.

Objective-C methods are resolved at runtime, and `str.className` is a shortcut for
`[str className]`, which means

> Send the `className` message to the object pointed to by `str`.

Therefore `str.className` and `arr.className` invoke the same method on the
same instance.

The declared type of the pointer (`NSString *`, `NSArray *`) is not used for the method
resolution. You could even call

```
[obj className];
```

with your `id obj`.

In the second case, the compiler can warn you about the assigment of different types of
pointers. That is not possible in the first case because `id` is a generic pointer that
can be converted from and to any Objective-C pointer (a bit similar to `void *` in the C language).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So basically, `str` or `arr` does not need to be the class type as what they were initialized? Why this kind of mechanism is used? Any good?

Comment: @Giantron: Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/DynamicBinding.html, perhaps that helps. - Also note that the *declaration* `NSString *str` does not *initialize* anything. `str` and `arr` are just pointers. Their declared type is only used by the compiler, but not at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I'm just quite used to that the pointer should point to what it is declared to be. It seems `objective-c` offers more flexibility through dynamic binding. And, since it's resolved at runtime, every pointer can be declared as `id`.. but it may not be good practice though?

Comment: @Giantron: The type should be as specific as possible. If you know (or expect) that the object is an instance of `SomeClass` or an instance of a subclass then use `SomeClass *`. If you know that it is some object conforming to a protocol then use `id<protocol>`. If you know nothing then use `id`. This allows the compiler to make as much error checking as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You only ever created one object, of one class. See, there are two parts to your code:

1. Actual instances of objects

   In your case, the only time you actually create an object is when you write @"x".
2. Pointers to those objects (variables containing memory addresses)

When you say

```
NSString* str
```

or

```
NSArray* arr
```

or

```
id obj
```

all you are doing is creating a pointer variable. Under the hood, a pointer variable is simply a variable that can hold a number. Like an int. Just that it is intended to contain the memory address of an object. You can think of a pointer variable as a napkin on which someone wrote the building number from the street address of a bungalow.

Then you are taking a second (and third) napkin and writing the same building number on it. However, instead of noting on the napkin that it's a bungalow, the napkin 'arr' actually says on it that this is an apartment building (NSArray). And on the 'obj' napkin you don't even bother writing what it is (id).

Just because your napkin says that this address refers to an apartment doesn't change the house at that number in your street.

The type you give to a pointer variable is merely a hint to the compiler, so it can warn you when you're getting your objects mixed up by accident. There is no conversion from one object type to the other performed when you write their address in a pointer variable of a different type. Usually, if you assign the address of an object of one type to a pointer variable of another type, you get an error message. But since you're going via the 'obj' variable, which is of type 'id', you're circumventing this check. 'id' is used for cases where all you care about is that you're dealing with an object.

E.g. NSArray keeps a list of objects of any type, but doesn't really care which type. So it uses 'id' as the type of the addresses it keeps around. This way, you only need one array class, not one NSStringArray, and another NSNumberArray etc. To make cases like this more convenient, whenever an 'id' variable is involved, the compiler doesn't warn and assumes you know what you're doing.